# Error Message Flashes for a Second Only

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to make a sign up form with javascript validation but the error message only flashes for a second.

I tried searching other similar questions but I couldn't find the answer...

This is my form code

```
<form method="post" name="signupForm">
    <div id="signup-form" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span id="error"></span>
        <div class="form-group" id="inputFirst">
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="firstname" placeholder="John" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="inputLast">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="lastname" placeholder="Doe" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="inputEmail">
            <label for="signup_email">Email Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="signup_email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="inputPassword">
            <label for="user_password">Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="user_password" name="password" placeholder="Create a Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" class="btn button">Sign Up</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my Validation Function

```
function validateForm() {
        var first= document.forms["signupForm"]["firstname"].value;
        var last = document.forms["signupForm"]["lastname"].value;
        var email= document.forms["signupForm"]["email"].value;
        var pass = document.forms["signupForm"]["password"].value;
        var msg = "";
        var valid= true;

        checkname = /[A-z]/;
        checkemail= /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;

        if(!/\w/.test(pass))
        {
            msg="Password can only contain [a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore)]";
            valid= false;
        }
        if(!checkemail.test(email))
        {
            msg="Email address Invalid";
            valid= false;
        }
        if(!checkname.test(first))
        {
            msg="First and Last Name can only contain alphabets";
            valid= false;
        }
        if(first==="" && last==="" && email==="" && pass==="")
        {
            msg="Please fill every field given below";
            valid= false;
        }
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = msg;
        return valid;

    }
```

Comment: onclick="return validateForm();" - you are submitting form, otherwise... That's why error message 'flashes for a second'.

Comment: In your function, accept the submit event as a parameter `function validateForm(ev) {` and then immediately do `ev.preventDefault()` to prevent the submission of the form. If it passes validation, then submit the form `document.forms['signupForm'].submit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return validateForm()`, this way when the validateForm will return false - it will stop the form from submitting.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var first= document.forms["signupForm"]["firstname"].value;
  var last = document.forms["signupForm"]["lastname"].value;
  var email= document.forms["signupForm"]["email"].value;
  var pass = document.forms["signupForm"]["password"].value;
  var msg = "";
  var valid= true;
debugger;
  checkname = /[A-z]/;
  checkemail= /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;

  if(!/\w/.test(pass))
  {
    msg="Password can only contain [a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore)]";
    valid= false;
  }
  if(!checkemail.test(email))
  {
    msg="Email address Invalid";
    valid= false;
  }
  if(!checkname.test(first))
  {
    msg="First and Last Name can only contain alphabets";
    valid= false;
  }
  if(first==="" && last==="" && email==="" && pass==="")
  {
    msg="Please fill every field given below";
    valid= false;
  }
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = msg;
  return valid;

}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="signupForm">
    <div id="signup-form" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span id="error"></span>
        <div class="form-group" id="inputFirst">
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="firstname" placeholder="John" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="inputLast">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="lastname" placeholder="Doe" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="inputEmail">
            <label for="signup_email">Email Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="signup_email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="inputPassword">
            <label for="user_password">Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="user_password" name="password" placeholder="Create a Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" class="btn button">Sign Up</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is probably still be submitting as you are not stopping the form submission. Your event handler is "onClick" on the submit button. This not necessarily stop the form.

You only see the error message for a split second because the page does a full page reload.

Your validation function should be bound to the "onSubmit" event instead.

```
 <form onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```